# python how to skip line in list display

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, python-2.7

i want the skip line between elements in list
this is my out put :
[image]

and this is my code :

```
output = net_connect.send_command(request.POST.get("cmds"), use_textfsm=True)
outputs.append(request.POST.get("cmds"))
outputs.append("\n")
outputs.append(output)
outputs.append("\n")
print(outputs)
```

cmds is for the cli input

and this is how i display outputs :

```
<div class="card col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card-header">
            <label> <h3>output : </h3></label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="card-body text-center">
            <textarea  rows="10" cols="80">{{outputs}} </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify, are you wanting to add a line break between each element in the output so that there is one element per line?

Comment: I think you mean to append the output to a string not a list. That way the `\n`would create a line break.

Comment: @Danoram i want for exmple line 1 show version line 2 the answer from router line 3 show ip int br line 4 the answer from router

Comment: @JakobF how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `print(outputs)`
use

```
for output in outputs:
    print(output)
```

and exclude the appending of "\n".
so finally your code must look like:

```
output = net_connect.send_command(request.POST.get("cmds"), use_textfsm=True)
outputs.append(request.POST.get("cmds"))

for output in outputs:
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me  :

```
<div class="card col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card-header">
            <label> <h3>output : </h3></label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="card-body text-center">
            <textarea  rows="10" cols="80"> {% for i in outputs %} {{i}}     {% endfor %}    </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is the result :
[image]